# Syntax issue using Show

Tags: plotting

In the Mathematica Book 5 there is an example under Graphics and Sound.  First they generate 3 plots and then display them like so:

```
Show[GraphicsArray[{{gh0, gjy},{gj1, gjy}]]
```

I realize that GraphicsArray has been replaced by GraphicsGrid. So the previous expression now is:

```
Show[GraphicsGrid[{{gh0, gjy},{gj1, gjy}]]
```

The next step is:

```
Show[%, Frame->True, FrameTicks-> None]
```

This should put a frame around the whole array of plots.  Instead I get this:

[image]

I don't want that box in the middle.  I wast a frame around the whole Array.  How is this now done?

Comment: `plot = Plot[x Sin[# x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ 
  Range[4]; Multicolumn[plot, 2, Frame -> True]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the option `Frame` in `GraphicsGrid`:

```
{gh0, gjy, gj1, gjy} = Plot[x Sin[# x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ Range[4];
GraphicsGrid[{{gh0, gjy}, {gj1, gjy}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]